# Prevent silent cast from false to pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

I have a function

```
void foo(int *bar)
{}
```

Visual Studio 2012 will now happily and without warnings compile if I call foo like this:

```
int main()
{
  foo(false);
  return 0;
}
```

If I however change foo(false) to foo(true) than I get an error:

```
1>main.cpp(132): error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'int *'
1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Any idea how I can make sure that I get an error when passing false, too? My only idea is to add a second private function "void foo(bool bar)". Then I indeed get the desired error stating that foo(bool bar) is private. But this only works when foo is called from outside the class and it clutters my interface.

Comment: Clang has a warning for that ...

Comment: Gcc gives a warning, too. But sadly only a small part of our code base is also compiled with non-Microsoft compilers...

Comment: Did you try increasing warning level?

Comment: Yes, I have Level 4 active.

Comment: clang now throws an error when set to C++11 or gnu++11 modes.

Comment: What would be really nice is a way to disallow treating `false` as `0` _everywhere_, for the purpose of preventing mistakes that are going to break compilation on other compilers. Even in MSVC2017, it doesn't even warn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, as to why it accepts `false` but not `true`: The literal false will be interpreted as the integral `0` and a literal `0` will convert to a null pointer of any type. `true` on the other hand cannot be converted to a pointer type as it converts to an integral `1`.

As to how to solve your problem: Your approach with an extra `bool` overload will work fine for both public and non-public callers *as long as you don't implement the private overload*. In that case public callers will get a compile error and member callers will get a linker error.

However, you may wish to consider additional things as well.

Does your function need to accept null pointers? If not, change it to accept by reference instead and the problem just goes away.

If your function really does need to accept null pointers then I would suggest in this case *to just trust your users* to call it correctly instead of cluttering your interface trying to prevent every possible misuse.

Comment: The reason for this is the following: I had foo(int *) and foo(bool). Then I refactored my code and foo(bool) became foo(someEnum). I relied on the compiler showing me all usages of foo(bool) which I had to convert and only after 10 minutes converting foo(true) started wondering why I don't get any errors about foo(false).

Answer (score 6):

### In C++11, you may write:

```
void foo(bool) = delete; // cannot be use by anybody (class itself included).
```

As vs2012 doesn't support `= delete`,

You may try this hack using SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, void>::type
foo(T* t);
```

### With the old C++98 way 'private without implementation':

```
private:            // Fail to compile from outside
    void foo(bool); // No implementation -> fail to link time if internally used.
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, bad it seems Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support this part of C++11 yet.

Comment: @fschmitt: I've just added a hack which may work with vs2012 (untested)

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for C++17, when Concepts can be used anywhere `auto` is in C++11, and write your signature as:

```
void foo( IsActually<int*>::template test x ) { }
```

... which actually looks pretty bad, but they may clean up the syntax by then.