# Is converting a bool (false) to a pointer legal in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

I've recently stumbled unto something strange: converting a boolean to pointer works in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 but not on GCC nor Clang (tried in 3.5).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(int *ptr)
{
    std::cout << "foo";
}

int main()
{
   foo(false);
}
```

Error in [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae1f5cfb56277d02):

```
    main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    main.cpp:13:13: error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void foo(int*)'
    foo(false);
             ^
```

My guess is that false is converted to 0 which is equivalent to NULL. Replacing the call to *foo* with `foo(true)` causes the compilation to fail with every compiler.

So my question is: is this code supposed to compile? I fail to see the benefit of converting false to a pointer, it seems to me that it would only be the cause of bugs after misuse / refactoring etc

Comment: Related: [Prevent silent cast from false to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21025179/3425536)

Comment: @DieterLücking I don't think it's duplicate, OP want to know is it allowed and which compiler (gcc, clang, vc) is correct.

Comment: Damn, I did search for it and failed to find anything relevant. Is it valid C++ though? And if so, why does clang error when compiling it? Is it a compiler bug or is it not really defined in the standard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should not be accepted since C++11.

See [Pointer conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Pointer_conversions) (emphasis mine):

> A null pointer constant (see `NULL`), can be converted to any pointer type, and the result is the null pointer value of that type. Such conversion (known as *null pointer conversion*) is allowed to convert to a cv-qualified type as a single conversion, that is, it's **not considered a combination of numeric and qualifying conversions**.

Note since C++11 a [null pointer constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) might be **an integer literal with value zero** (or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`), while `false` is not, it's a [boolean literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bool_literal).

And until C++11 null pointer constant is defined as **an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero**, while `false` is fine. ([GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8edf6821826366b1) will give a warning for it.)

From the standard, `$4.10/1 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]` (emphasis mine)

> A null pointer constant is **an integer literal** (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.
>
> The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified
> type is **a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer
> conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4)**.

Comment: Note that this only applies to C++11 with [issue 903](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903) incorporated. As C++11 was originally published, a null pointer constant was "an integral constant expression ...", which `false` is. I've recently addressed that in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37214551/1782465).